# Get the tables referenced by a view view using a function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

I want to get tables referenced by a view and display them.

I have two tables: `test1` and `test2`

I've created a view, which references these tables

```
CREATE VIEW First_View 
AS 
   SELECT * FROM test1 
UNION 
   SELECT * FROM test2;
```

I have created one table which contains the view details like `view id` and `view name` as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE View_Details
(
view_id int,
view_name varchar
);
```

and inserted a record into it.

```
INSERT INTO view_details values(1,'First_View');
```

Now I am creating a function with one parameter `v_id` that is `view_id` and want to get all tables, which are referenced by the `view_namt`.

I'm doing this, but I'm getting nothing in Messages:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION For_testing(v_id INT)
RETURNS VOID AS
$$
Declare
    var varchar;
    v_name varchar;
BEGIN
    SELECT view_name INTO v_name from view_details where view_id = v_id;

    FOR var IN SELECT Table_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
                        WHERE View_Name = v_name LOOP
    RAISE INFO '%',VAR;

    END LOOP;
END;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Call Function:

```
SELECT for_testing(1);
```

Comment: I'd make var record and RAISE INFO '%',VAR. Table_NAME;

Comment: @user3222580, I did too. But still getting nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `SELECT lower(view_name) INTO v_name from view_details where view_id = v_id;`
because it should be in double quotes to be First_View... I mean dictionary will change First_View to lower(First_View) if you dont use "First_View" when create a view...

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is the case sensitive of `view name`. As you can see that the `view_name` have inserted as `First_View`, in which F and V are capital. So I come to know with the solution for this:

First we need to convert the upper case letters to lower by using `lower()` function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION For_testing(v_id INT)
RETURNS VOID AS
$$
Declare
   var varchar;
   v_name varchar;
BEGIN
   SELECT view_name INTO v_name from view_details where view_id = v_id;

   /* Solved here*/
  v_name := lower(v_name);

   FOR var IN SELECT Table_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
                    WHERE View_Name = v_name LOOP
   RAISE INFO '%',VAR;

END LOOP;
END;
$$
language plpgsql;
```